# Should I use a controller class for an object?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm confused. And lost. Teaching myself C# and have a question on setting up my objects. My first attempt through I created an object and had that object handle all things itself. So say I had the following class:

```
class Customer{
    public string customerName{get; set;}

    public Customer(string customerName){
      this.customerName = customerName;
   }

    public int UpdateCustomer(){
       ///do stuff
    }
}
```

Then from my form, if someone pushed the update button (just an example), I would simply create a new Customer, set the name, and then call UpdateCustomer. That just doesn't seem like a good flow and doesn't feel right for some reason.

Should I be call UpdateCustomer directly from my forms? Or should I create a controller to handle all things Customer?

Comment: Is this about MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in OOP are allowed to have both **state** and **behavior**. There is nothing fundamentally wrong with that. For example, lets say we wanted to say "Hi" to a customer, a traditional model would put:

```
public void SayHello() { Console.WriteLine("Hi!"); }
```

On the `Customer` class. There are lots of other examples. That being said, there are plenty of cases where separating the state and behavior is advantageous. In particular, its immensely helpful when using dependency injection, as the "state" objects are typically not injected, and so don't have immediate access to the behavior's dependencies. In addition, certain architectural patterns (like Actor-Model) proscribe a fairly strict separation of behavior and state.

Basically, it comes down to (as does so much of software engineering) as designing for what makes sense in the particular time and place that is in question. Without seeing the implementation of `UpdateCustomer` it is hard to say what the right answer is here, but its certainly not inherently wrong.